# InvocationTargetException in Hello world

Tags: java, applet, japplet, invocationtargetexception

I have a JApplet that works when run by appletviewer but not when run by Firefox or IE. It displays an empty rectangle with "Error. Click for details." Clicking on it brings up the window that says, "Application Error. RuntimeException. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException."

I planned to find the source of the error by starting with a Hello world program and adding parts of the complete applet until the error happened again. Instead, even the Hello world program produced the error.

The compiler is from the jdk1.7.0_45 release. For this test, the commands and all files except the compiler are in the Desktop folder. The commands (minus the digital signature), source code, and HTML are pasted below.

```
set path=%path%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin"
javac sampleApplet.java
jar cvfm sampleApplet.jar sampleApplet.mf sampleApplet.class
(This is where I sign the code. I don't think that's the source of the error.)
```

Text in sampleApplet.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class sampleApplet extends JApplet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("Hello world.", 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Text in sampleApplet.mf

```
Main-Class: sampleApplet
```

Text in sampleApplet.html

```html
<html>
<head><title>sample applet</title></head>
<body>
Before applet.<br>
<applet code = "sampleApplet.class" archive = "sampleApplet.jar" width = "1020" height = "584">
</applet>
<br>After applet.<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Dump thread stack is very long.

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode, sharing):

"ConsoleTraceListener" daemon prio=4 tid=0x04d79400 nid=0xadc in Object.wait() [0x0626f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29cd7510> (a com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$BoundedStringBuffer)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$ConsoleWriterThread.run(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29cd7510> (a com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$BoundedStringBuffer)

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=4 tid=0x04d7b000 nid=0x1194 waiting on condition [0x06aaf000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x24c10930> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=6 tid=0x04d7a800 nid=0xa50 waiting on condition [0x066ef000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x2a054870> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-EventQueue-1" prio=6 tid=0x00ef9800 nid=0xca0 waiting on condition [0x0604e000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleHelper.dumpAllStacksImpl(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleHelper.dumpAllStacks(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.ui.SwingConsoleWindow$3.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent$ActionStandin.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"JVM[id=1]-Heartbeat" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00efa400 nid=0x12ac in Object.wait() [0x0619f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d72c10> (a sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$Heartbeat)
at sun.plugin2.main.server.HeartbeatThread.run(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d72c10> (a sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$Heartbeat)

"AWT-EventQueue-2" prio=4 tid=0x00efa000 nid=0x12b4 waiting on condition [0x05c3f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x29d72d68> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Applet 1 LiveConnect Worker Thread" prio=4 tid=0x00ef7400 nid=0xc6c in Object.wait() [0x0570f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d72e68> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d72e68> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Browser Side Object Cleanup Thread" prio=6 tid=0x00ef9400 nid=0x1054 in Object.wait() [0x05f1f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d72ef0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d72ef0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$BrowserSideObjectCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

"CacheCleanUpThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00ef8c00 nid=0xe58 in Object.wait() [0x05d1f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d72f10> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d72f10> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)

"CacheMemoryCleanUpThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00ef8800 nid=0x1174 in Object.wait() [0x05b4f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d73000> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d73000> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$LoadedResourceCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

"MemoryCache-DelayedCleanup" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00ef8000 nid=0x1320 in Object.wait() [0x05bcf000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d73090> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d73090> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"SysExecutionTheadCreator" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00ef5400 nid=0xd98 in Object.wait() [0x0580f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d730a0> (a sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator.run(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d730a0> (a sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator)

"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x00ef7800 nid=0x12e0 waiting on condition [0x0597f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x29d73178> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00ef6c00 nid=0xc30 runnable [0x0113f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=6 tid=0x00ef6800 nid=0x5c8 in Object.wait() [0x059ff000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d732e0> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d732e0> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00ef6000 nid=0x9bc in Object.wait() [0x0545f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d73370> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d73370> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Java Plug-In Pipe Worker Thread (Client-Side)" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00ef5c00 nid=0x7b4 runnable [0x0592f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.plugin2.os.windows.Windows.ReadFile0(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.os.windows.Windows.ReadFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.ipc.windows.WindowsNamedPipe.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.message.transport.NamedPipeTransport$SerializerImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.message.transport.NamedPipeTransport$SerializerImpl.readByte(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.message.AbstractSerializer.readInt(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.message.transport.SerializingTransport.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Timer-0" prio=6 tid=0x00ef4c00 nid=0xacc in Object.wait() [0x056bf000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d736d8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d736d8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Thread-0" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00ef4800 nid=0x7e4 waiting on condition [0x054cf000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.util.SecurityBaseline$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"traceMsgQueueThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00ef4000 nid=0xe2c in Object.wait() [0x0501f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29cb1be8> (a java.util.ArrayList)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at com.sun.deploy.trace.Trace$TraceMsgQueueChecker.run(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29cb1be8> (a java.util.ArrayList)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00ef3c00 nid=0xeac runnable [0x00000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00efdc00 nid=0x850 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00ef3400 nid=0xc18 runnable [0x00000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00ef3000 nid=0x1130 runnable [0x00000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x00e88000 nid=0xe48 in Object.wait() [0x048ef000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d739d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d739d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00e83400 nid=0xf04 in Object.wait() [0x0481f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d73a58> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d73a58> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x0065d800 nid=0x134 in Object.wait() [0x00d8f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x29d73a60> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x29d73a60> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$1.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter$1.wait(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter.runAndWait(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.main(Unknown Source)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00e7dc00 nid=0x13a0 runnable
"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00f1d000 nid=0x124c waiting on condition

)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.main(Unknown Source)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00e7dc00 nid=0x13a0 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00f1d000 nid=0x124c waiting on condition
```

Comment: I guess other applets work fine in the browser? If you turn on the java console in the java settings, what's the stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I went to the tutorials at http://docs.oracle.com and the applets appear as they should.

Comment: What version of Java JRE do you have? It's possible, that jre blocks your applet because of missing attributes in manifest file.

Comment: jre7/release has this line. I didn't find any explicit statement like "JRE version =" so if that's not it, how would I find it?
JAVA_VERSION="1.7.0"

Comment: There's another possible clue. If I double click the jar file or type sampleApplet.jar on the command line, nothing happens. Some tutorials say that should start the applet.

Comment: The applet works if I upload it to the website and then run it from there like I'm the customer. The InvocationTargetException happens when the URL is the path and file name where I edit the .html. So the applet works but I can't test it offline.